# Func<TIn, TResult> On generic linq

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, .net-core, func

I've a list of strings.

```
List<string> myData = new List<string>
            {
                "abcdefghi1",
                "abcdefghi2"
                "abcdefghi3"
            };
```

If I manually made the following LINQ, it works perfectly.

```
var myObjectList = (from s in myData 
                    select new myObject
                    {
                        Prop1 = s.Substring(0,3),
                        Prop2 = s.Substring(4,1)...
                    }).ToList();
```

When I check the "select new myObject" type, it's a `Func<string, T>`.

If I create the follow method

```
List<T> getMyObjects(List<string> myData, Func<string, T> selector) where T : class 
{
    return (from s in myData select selector).ToList();
}
```

And call it like

```
var myObjectList = getMyObjects(data, 
                      value => new myObject 
                      {
                        Prop1 = value.Substring(0,3),
                        Prop2 = value.Substring(4,1)
                      });
```

It returns a list of `{System.Func<string, MyObject>}` instead of a list of

Any idea on how to accomplish that ?

Br,

Answer (score 2):

You're selecting the mapping function instead of the result of using it to map.

```
List<T> getMyObjects(List<string> myData, Func<string, T> selector) where T : class 
{
    return (from s in myData select selector).ToList();
}
```

should likely be

```
List<T> getMyObjects(List<string> myData, Func<string, T> selector) where T : class 
{
    return (from s in myData select selector(s)).ToList();
    //                                      ^^^ get the result of your selector delegate against the string.
}
```

Which, as @Camilo Terevinto points out, can be further simplified to:

```
List<T> getMyObjects(List<string> myData, Func<string, T> selector) where T : class 
{
    return myData.Select(selector).ToList();
}
```

Comment: That's correct.

Thanks for the help, really missed that.

I'll mark as right in 7 mins.

Br,